# Only update one attribute instead of whole table

Tags: php

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->updateItem($itemID, array( 'qty' => $qty));
$quote->save();
?>
```

The above updates pricing when i only want to update qty. Code is in frontend. Base price is set to 0 when I call the above script.

I am updating the sales_quote_item table

Comment: can you explain your query more briefly?

Comment: Gets the current custom quote from the session and updates the sales_flat_quote_item tbl with custom quantity